# JCenter сломался

Tags: android, android-studio

Пришёл с выходных и тут на тебе ошибочка

```
Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.2).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.2/builder-3.1.2.jar
```

Я так понимаю вопрос "чинится" или кто то уже нашёл решение этого вопроса?

Вот [в твиттере](https://twitter.com/hashtag/jcenter?lang=en) ещё какое то движение происходит по данному вопросу.

Comment: А разве все андроид-приблуды не в репозитории `google()` (ака https://maven.google.com)? В свой `Build.gradle` загляните, есть ли он там. А в `jcenter` действительно нет такой версии: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/

Comment: @woesss я тоже было так подумал, но `realm` увы не там, поэтому не сработало.